# Non-equivalent definitions in proofs

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

In chapter 3 of "How to Read and Do Proofs", Daniel Solow speaks about how definitions are useful in proofs. He gives an example where, for one proposition, there is more than one definition that can be used to prove the proposition. For instance, for the proposition "n is an even integer", there could be two definitions of "even" used. (1) n is an integer whose remainder on dividing by 2 is 0 or (2) n is an integer that can be expressed as 2 times some integer.

Solow suggests that in a case like this, one should show that the two definitions are equivalent (i.e., A -> B and B -> A). It so happens that (1) and (2) are indeed equivalent. My question is, are there any cases where the definitions that from a proposition are not equivalent and, if so, does this pose any problems in constructing a proof?

Comment: Generally, if there are two non-equivalent definitions of a statement, they describe different things and will be called differently. "$x$ is prime" and "$x$ has at most two distinct divisors $d \ge 1$" often coincide in the positive integers, but are not equivalent because of the number $1$ (not a prime, only one divisor). So we won't call *both* definitions the same thing, because they describe different things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At any one time, you should only use one definition for a term or construct or symbol, etc. The problem of proving definitions are equivalent is mostly to make sure that different authors are talking about the same thing.

I remember preparing some lectures from Smullyan-Fitting's "Set Theory and the Continuum Problem" (before Dover published a paperback). I lost the book, so I found someone else's lecture notes to fill in my gaps. My presentation had some inconsistencies. My advisor took me back and found that the notes had been using a different, albeit forgivably misunderstood, definition of a term from the book.

So yes, it is important to check that definitions match. They should. If anything is defined in two ways that are not equivalent, you have inconsistency, hence you can prove anything you want regardless of truth.